# How to Mute ongoing instance of SpeechSynthesisUtterance

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I am using SpeechSynthesisUtterance for text to speech in my browser. How can I mute and unmute the ongoing speech on button click?

Answer (score 2):

You may change the **SpeechSynthesisUtterance.volume** property. For muting make `SpeechSynthesisUtterance.volume = 0`.

Comment: And to add that to unmute the default value is 1.
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html#dfn-utterancevolume

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no way to mute the ongoing speech. You can cancel the running speech, mute the volume using SpeechSynthesisUtterance.volume property and restart the speech.